# Problems accessing nextcloud SSL encrypted with webdav client python

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, webdav, pycurl, nextcloud

I was using a python script to access my nextcloud server, all cool, no problems, but i decided to encrypt nextcloud with SSL self signed, and there goes my script... Nextcloud is deplayed in Apache, and it has the directive

Redirect "/" "https://IP"

making all request go to https.

I am using webdav client in python with this options

```
self.options = {'webdav_login':'user', 'webdav_password':'pass', 'webdav_hostname':  http://ip, 'webdav_root': 'nextcloud/remote.php/webdav'}
```

Those options where perfect with http, but when i try to do any request to nextcloud with those options i get webdav exceptions such as RemoteParentNotFound.

I tried to change the http://ip to https://ip, but if i do that, pycurl raise the exception  NotConnection.

Can someone help me to make it work or recommend me any method to upload, delete, etc into nextcloud using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. To make pycurl/webdav.client verify successfully the certificate append it to /etc/ssl/cert/ca-certificate.crt in Linux.